# Trying to unfreeze panes with openpyxl causes damages

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am attempting to read worksheets with openpyxl and unfreeze the panes. Openpyxl documentation indicated that to do that, I would set the worksheet.freeze_panes to `"A1"` or `None`. I am doing that (see code below)

```
wb=load_workbook(path)
ws=wb["Sheet"]
ws.freeze_panes=ws["A1"]
wb.save(path)
```

but when I try to open the workbook, Excel says

```
'We found a problem with some content, do you want us to try to recover as much as we can?"
```

It then gives a log of the repairs which says

```
"Removed Feature: View from /xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml part"
```

However, when I try to freeze any other pane, I don't get any issues. Has anyone else ran into this problem? Is there something I'm doing wrong? Would appreciate any insight. I am using openpyxl version 2.5.0 and python version 3.5.2.

Comment: Since you do not run into this issue for any other pane, the best way the stackoverflow community can help you is if you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that people can have a look at to see what might have gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at the source that does this: freezing to `A1` is supposed to do nothing. However, I've no plans to change this code. It's much better to work with a sheet view (`ws.views.sheetViews[0]`), but you'll need to look at the format specification for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestion above by Charlie Clark the following code works for me and does not produces the error.

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
ws = wb.active
ws.views.sheetView[0].pane = openpyxl.worksheet.views.Pane() # makes pane empty
ws.views.sheetView[0].selection[0] = openpyxl.worksheet.views.Selection()
ws.views.sheetView[0].topLeftCell = 'A1' # scroll to top left corner
wb.save(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your problem while trying to solve my own problem:
My problem was that using freeze_panes hides the top rows/columns if the spreadsheet didn't show them upon closing Excel.

*(If you are freezing the panes when your view was outside of the frozen cell,
(For example, open a spreadsheet in Excel, scroll down and to the right and save, then try to freeze panes using openpyxl), then the frozen view will be messed up)*

The solution was to unfreeze the panes through excel and then to try again in python, but trying to unfreeze using `freeze_panes = None` caused the same problem you had with the message from Excel.

First, in case you are trying to unfreeze the panes because freezing them messed up the view, then the solution is to change the view to show A1 **before** freezing panes:

```
# Go to cell A1 - Mandatory for freeze_panes to work
ws.sheet_view.topLeftCell = 'A1'
# Freeze Panes on cell E5
ws.freeze_panes = 'E5'
```

---

The solution to your problem is a bit more tricky:

To recreate the situation, I saved an empty spreadsheet in Excel, then opened it using openpyxl, froze and unfroze panes and saved:

```
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(xlspath)
ws=wb.active
ws.freeze_panes = 'E5'
ws.freeze_panes = 'A1'
wb.save(filename=xlspath)
```

To understand why it fails in Excel, I am looking at one of two fields:

1. `ws.sheet_view.selection` - This is a list with three Selection objects in it, each with a different pane - notice none of them is `'topLeft'` which is mandatory
2. `ws.views.sheetView[0].selection` - shows the same as the above (At least in this scenario, I'm not completely sure if there are other scenarios)

I suggest removing all the objects except one, and change its pane to `'topLeft'`:

```
ws.sheet_view.selection=[ws.sheet_view.selection[0]]
ws.sheet_view.selection[0].pane='topLeft'
wb.save(filename=xlspath)
```

This fixed the issue for me and allowed me to open the spreadsheet in Excel without errors.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the source and fixed using this:

```py
sheet.views.sheetView[0] = openpyxl.worksheet.views.SheetView()
```

It reconstructs the SheetView object.